# Front End Access no servidor

Tags: microsoft-access

Normalmente colocamos o Back End no servidor e o Front End na máquina local.

Existe algum problema (talvez de performance) em deixar uma cópia do FE no servidor para cada usuário e colocar apenas o link de cada um na máquina local?

Ou seja, eu teria no servidor uma instância do FE para cada usuário:

```
FE_Joao.accdb
FE_Pedro.accdb
FE_Maria.accdb
```

E na máquina de cada um deles, um link:

```
FE_Joao_atalho
FE_Pedro_atalho
FE_Maria_atalho
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

Na prática é bem possível, principalmente se os usuários não ficam abrindo e fechando o programa diversas vezes. Por outro lado, é importante considerar os *trade-offs* e certas restrições que a aplicação precisa respeitar (como não gravar arquivos na mesma pasta do prgorama).

## Minha experiência com executáveis na rede

Sem saber em detalhes como funciona a aplicação é difícil dar uma resposta absoluta. Primeiro vou relatar algumas experiências ruins que tive com uma solução parecida:

Numa empresa em que trabalhei todos tinham que usar um sistema interno, o qual era acessado pela rede através de um link para o executável. Dependendo de quanto a rede estava congestionada, o atraso para abrir o programa (em relação aos programas locais) era bastante perceptível. Por outro lado, após o executável ser aberto, não há diferença de desempenho.

Como usava este programa todos os dias, a princípio tentei colocar atalhos no Menu Iniciar e na Área de Trabalho. Porém, frequentemente haviam bloqueios da tela ao tentar acessar o menu ou ao minimizar os programas para ver a Área de Trabalho. Isso ocorria provavelmente porque o Windows estava lendo o executável pela rede para atualizar o ícone do atalho. Digo isso porque frequentemente os demais ícones estavam normais, menos aquele, e a tela ficava bloqueada até que ele aparecesse. Além do ícone, o Windows lê várias informações do arquivo por diversos motivos. Já cansei de esperar em ocasiões onde estava navegando em diretórios na rede e o Windows levava vários minutos até conseguir listar alguns poucos arquivos.

Depois disso, eu removi os atalhos e configurei o Agendador de Tarefas para abrir o programa num horário agendado todos os dias. Entretanto, tive problemas algumas vezes relacionados à segurança. Quando acessávamos o diretório no servidor via Windows Explorer, ele algumas vezes solicitava que digitássemos novamente as credenciais necessárias. No caso do Agendador de Tarefas, caso ele não consiga acessar o programa na rede, ele simplesmente não pedia as credenciais e falhava. Outro problema é que as vezes o Windows não "confia" no executável e, ao invés de perguntar se você quer mesmo abrir o programa, ele simplesmente falha silenciosamente.

Enfim, eu sei que são casos isolados, mas é importante considerar que existem algumas limitações nessa solução.

## Considerações gerais

Agora, vou tentar considerar alguns pontos gerais:

### Desempenho

Usar executáveis na rede irá causar um atraso na inicialização e cada vez que for necessário ler um arquivo. Como alguns programas fazem uso de arquivos de configuração, cada vez que for necessário ler um arquivo o atraso de repetirá. Por outro lado, após as leituras não deve haver impacto no desempenho.

### Disponibilidade

Supondo que não haja um problema na rede e o servidor de banco de dados esteja em outro local, o sistema ficará indisponível quando por algum motivo os arquivos não forem acessíveis. É uma preocupação a mais, pois você acrescentou um nó adicional na rede para gerenciar.

### Distribuição

A distribuição de novas versões do aplicativo será facilitada, embora numa rede seja possível realizar outras formas de atualização, como via um script administrativo ou mesmo uma ferramenta de auto atualização.

Por outro lado, os usuários não poderão escolher se querem ou não atualizar seus sistemas. Um *bug* novo ou uma versão indevidamente publicada afetará todos eles, sempre.

### Concorrência

Se o sistema grava arquivos em seu próprio diretório, isso terá que ser alterado para gravar num diretório local fixo no disco da estação do usuário ou no registro. Caso contrário, cada usuário sobrescreverá o arquivo dos outros.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação. E qual seria o programa de auto atualização para eu não precisar ficar copiando de máquina em máquina?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva A atualização automática que eu mencionei é algum programa ou script (separado da sua aplicação)  executado no login do usuário que verifica se tem alguma versão nova do programa na rede (por exemplo, lendo um arquivo texto no servidor). Se tiver ele copia os arquivos necessários por cima do que tiver na máquina do usuário. Enfim, existem infinitas possibilidades de como fazer isso e não é muito complicado.